# How to get a circle of surrounding grid cells based on origin cell

Tags: c#, math

I have a simple 2d grid. Currently I am getting the center cell (blue) and getting surrounding cells in a square for a specific range (Coord is a class with int x, int z):

```
public List<WorldCell> GetSurroundingCells(Coord coord, int distance)
{
    List<WorldCell> matches = new List<WorldCell>();

    for (int x = coord.x - distance; x <= coord.x + distance; x++)
    {
        for (int z = coord.z - distance; z <= coord.z + distance; z++)
        {
            WorldObjectCell cell = GetCell(new Coord(x, z));

            if (cell != null)
                matches.Add(cell);
        }
    }
    
    return matches;
}
```

This works fine. However now I want to get all the surrounding cells in a circle, ie:

[image]

I cannot figure out the math required to always return a "circle" of surrounding cells based in inputs `originCoord` & `distance`.

EDIT: Using Nintos answer:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not that complicated. Pythagoras' theorem is enough here. If this gives you incorrect results, I think tweaking it a little bit should be enough to correct those errors (for example, if you get too many cells, try decreasing the distance by .45).

```
//calculation of end coordinates before loop to hopefully increase efficiency
int OX = orginCoord.getX();
int OY = orginCoord.getY();
int EX = distance + OX;
int EY = distance + OY;
int SQ = distance * distance;//If the result looks weird, try changing this to a float/double.
//The for loops check each part of the grid in a square with a side length of distance*2 + 1,
//therefore including each possible circle cell. Can probably optimized, but I don't know how.
for(int x = OX - distance; x<= EX; x++){
    for(int y = OY - distance; y<=EY; y++){
        int c = x - OX;//Use of relative coordinates
        int d = y - OY;
        if((c*c+d*d)<=SQ){//This uses pythagoras to check if the cell is within distance,
            // squared to avoid using root functions
            WorldObjectCell cell = GetCell(new Coord(x, z));
            if (cell != null)
                matches.Add(cell);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ill make sure to try this as soon as I get home. PS this is complicated to me :)

Comment: are you sure this is right? If I input a distance of 5, and x = 34 and y = 13. The following happens: 
`(x * x + y * y) = 905`
`SQ = 25`

Meaning we are never even close to getting into that if-statement in the loops.

Comment: sorry, I goofed up. I forgot to use relative coordinates.
The formula should look a little bit different, give me a moment to edit

Comment: thanks!! That seems to have solved that issue :) The circles I get are a bit weird, Ill post an image to my question to show you what I mean. Any idea how I can tweak it to get some more rounded circles?

Comment: As said, the distance probably plays a role here. As commented, try changing the SQ to float and if that not works, also reduce the distance value by .45 before calculating SQ. That probably will reduce the 'weirdness' of the circle, but I'm not sure, as I am guessing here, unable to do it myself right now. The important part here is the value you're subtracting from the distance.

Comment: Apparently making it `(c*c+d*d)<SQ` makes the circle more or less perfect! Thanks!

Comment: you dont happen to know a quick formula to get all the edge cells?

Comment: try iterating through each cell and check for adjacent cells.
It's inefficient tho

Comment: if you have time later I have a question regarding this herE:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/184640/getting-the-edge-cells-in-a-list-of-cells-on-a-2d-grid-and-knowing-which-neighb